# SQL Sum is counting more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having difficulty with this. This query worked fine in calculating the sums until I put the first inner join in. In the table tbl_companies there are multiple entries per company, for example the table could look like this:

```
priority      company     externalip
1             bla         9.9.9.9
1             bla         3.3.3.3
1             company2    3.56.6.6
```

In the below query the sum (that calculates As TotalWithoutNew and TotalAllId is doubling when there is more than one entry for the company, and tripling if there is three etc. What I want it to do is simply bring back the priority from the table tbl_companies

```
SELECT b.company, 
       b.priority, 
       i.concom, 
       Coalesce (SUM(CASE 
                       WHEN c.category_id = '30' THEN 0 
                       ELSE t.logmins 
                     END), 0)       AS totalwithoutnew, 
       Coalesce (SUM(t.logmins), 0) AS totalallid 
FROM   helpdesk3.dbo.inquiry AS i 
       INNER JOIN [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] AS b 
         ON i.concom = b.company COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as 
       INNER JOIN timelog AS t 
         ON t.inquiry_id = i.inquiry_id 
       INNER JOIN prod AS p 
         ON i.prod_id = p.prod_id 
       INNER JOIN category AS c 
         ON p.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE  ( Datepart(yyyy, escdate) = 2011 ) 
GROUP  BY i.concom, 
          b.company, 
          b.priority 
ORDER  BY totalwithoutnew DESC, 
          b.priority DESC
```

Comment: Do priority, company and externalip (together) uniquely identify tbl_companies records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the query to avoid multiple results from tbl_companies.

```
select distinct b.company, 
       b.priority, 
       x.concom, 
       x.totalwithoutnew, 
       x.totalallid 
FROM    (
            SELECT i.concom, 
                   Coalesce (SUM(CASE 
                                   WHEN c.category_id = '30' THEN 0 
                                   ELSE t.logmins 
                                 END), 0)       AS totalwithoutnew, 
                   Coalesce (SUM(t.logmins), 0) AS totalallid 
            FROM   helpdesk3.dbo.inquiry AS i 
                   INNER JOIN timelog AS t 
                     ON t.inquiry_id = i.inquiry_id 
                   INNER JOIN prod AS p 
                     ON i.prod_id = p.prod_id 
                   INNER JOIN category AS c 
                     ON p.category_id = c.category_id 
            WHERE  ( Datepart(yyyy, escdate) = 2011 ) 
            GROUP  BY i.concom 
            ) x
INNER JOIN [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] AS b 
          ON x.concom = b.company COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as 

ORDER  BY x.totalwithoutnew DESC, 
          b.priority DESC
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked fine, there was an errant comma and I added a distinct in the initial stage but this is what I needed. Thanks Johan!

Comment: Oh, I see. I was just modifying your original query, so I must have missed the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your join from the `INQUIRY` table to the `tbl_companies` table is going to generate a set of three rows (when there are three companies) so the next join to the `TIMELOG` table is also going to have three values for each TIMELOG.LOGMINS column - therefore it follows that the `COALESCE (SUM(CASE WHEN C.CATEGORY_ID = '30' THEN 0 ELSE t.LOGMINS END), 0) AS TotalWithoutNew` calculation will be tripled.

```
select 
...
FROM helpdesk3.dbo.INQUIRY AS i 
inner join [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] As B ON i.CONCOM = B.company COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
INNER JOIN TIMELOG AS t ON t.INQUIRY_ID = i.INQUIRY_ID 
...
```

If you want a single company to appear in the select and not multiply up the sum remove the join to tbl_companies from the where clause and the group by clause.  Something along these lines should work (although without knowing the exact structure of the data I can't be certain):

```
select 
(select company from [tbl_companies] where company = i.concom) as company,
(select priority from [tbl_companies] where company = i.concom) as priority,
...
FROM helpdesk3.dbo.INQUIRY AS i 
INNER JOIN TIMELOG AS t ON t.INQUIRY_ID = i.INQUIRY_ID 
...
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get around that?

Comment: I've put in a workaround, which will work if the company and priority columns are the same for each inquiry - if they are different then I'd suggest using a temporary table to hold inquiry/company information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. Assuming that priority, company and externalip uniquely identify tbl_companies records, I suggest:

```
SELECT b.company, 
       b.priority, 
       i.concom, 
       Coalesce (SUM(CASE 
                       WHEN c.category_id = '30' THEN 0 
                       ELSE t.logmins 
                     END), 0) / COUNT(DISTINCT b.externalip)  AS totalwithoutnew, 
       Coalesce (SUM(t.logmins), 0) / COUNT(DISTINCT b.externalip) AS totalallid 
FROM   helpdesk3.dbo.inquiry AS i 
       INNER JOIN [Check].[dbo].[tbl_companies] AS b 
         ON i.concom = b.company COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as 
       INNER JOIN timelog AS t 
         ON t.inquiry_id = i.inquiry_id 
       INNER JOIN prod AS p 
         ON i.prod_id = p.prod_id 
       INNER JOIN category AS c 
         ON p.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE  ( Datepart(yyyy, escdate) = 2011 ) 
GROUP  BY i.concom, 
          b.company, 
          b.priority 
ORDER  BY totalwithoutnew DESC, 
          b.priority DESC
```